# printf bash - print text in the middle of existing line surrounded by marks

Tags: bash

It doesn't seem that simple. At least for me.

I need to have a variable in printf text. **It's something like:**

```
FOO="User data"
+++++++++++++++++++ $FOO +++++++++++++++++++++
```

Would output

```
+++++++++++++++++++ User Data +++++++++++++++++++++
```

---

**But**

```
FOO="Fooooooo barrrr"
+++++++++++++++++++ $FOO +++++++++++++++++++++
```

Should output

```
++++++++++++++++ Fooooooo barrrr ++++++++++++++++++
```

---

**And**

```
FOO="Foooooooooooooooooooo barrrrr"
+++++++++++++++++++ $FOO +++++++++++++++++++++
```

Should be

```
+++++++++ Foooooooooooooooooooo barrrrr +++++++++++
```

As you can see I need a variable to be in the middle of n-length line, surrounded by `+` mark. How to achieve that using printf and other default-available commands?

(Debian 8)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? I believe you have to use letter count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
linelen=100
char="+"
text=$1
len=$(echo -n $text | wc -m)
fillerlen=$((($linelen - $len - 2) / 2))
filler=$(printf "$char%.0s" $(seq 1 $fillerlen))

echo $filler $text $filler
```

Comment: @Cyrus' answer is better, though, as this answer does not always output `linelen` characters (it's one off on odd values of `len`).

Answer (score 6):

```
declare -i x1 x2 x3 width
foo="User data"
width=50                # total width
x2=${#foo}+2            # length of $foo and 2 whitespaces
x1=(50-x2)/2            # length of first part
x3=$width-x1-x2         # length of last part
for ((i=1;i<=$x1;i++)); do echo -n "+"; done
echo -n " $foo "
for ((i=1;i<=$x3;i++)); do echo -n "+"; done
```

Output:

```
+++++++++++++++++++ User data ++++++++++++++++++++
```

With `foo="stackoverflow.com"`:

```
+++++++++++++++ stackoverflow.com ++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 2):

In the format string for `printf`, you can specify the "precision" of a string with `%${p}s`, where `$p` is the precision. You can take advantage of that by printing nothing (expanding to a space) the desired number of times and then translating the spaces into "+":

```
$ p=10
$ printf "%${p}s\n" | tr ' ' +
++++++++++
```

This function takes the length of your line and the string you want to put in its centre, then prints it padded with plus signs:

```
pad () {
    len=$1
    string=$2

    # ${#string} expands to the length of $string
    n_pad=$(( (len - ${#string} - 2) / 2 ))

    printf "%${n_pad}s" | tr ' ' +
    printf ' %s ' "$string"
    printf "%${n_pad}s\n" | tr ' ' +
}
```

Works like this:

```
$ pad 50 Test
++++++++++++++++++++++ Test ++++++++++++++++++++++
$ pad 50 "A longer string to be padded"
++++++++++ A longer string to be padded ++++++++++
```

Notice how you have to quote strings consisting of more than one word, or only the first one will be used.

If the length of your line is not divisible by 2, the padding will be rounded down, but will always be symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
n=50; # You can change the value of n as you please.
var="fooo baar";
size=${#var}
n=$(( n - size ))
n=$(( n / 2 ))
s=$(printf "%-${n}s" "*")
echo "${s// /*} "$var" ${s// /*}" #white-spaces included here.
```